# Jest.fn - return value returns undefined when using jest.mock

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have the following file I'm trying to write unit tests for:

```
import { document } from '../../globals';
const Overlay = () => {
  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName()); // this outputs 'undefined'
};
```

I'm struggling to mock the `getElementsByTagName` function. My test looks like this.

```
import { document } from '../../globals';
jest.mock('../../globals', () => ({
  document: {
    getElementsByTagName: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('foo')
  }
}));
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName()); // this outputs 'foo'
```

But unfortunately, the `console.log` in the top file always outputs `undefined`. It can see the document object and the `getElementsByTagName` mock, but the return value is always `undefined`.

If I `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName)` I get the following:

```
{ getElementsByTagName:
   { [Function: mockConstructor]
     _isMockFunction: true,
     getMockImplementation: [Function],
     mock: [Getter/Setter],
     mockClear: [Function],
     mockReset: [Function],
     mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
     mockReturnValue: [Function],
     mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
     mockImplementation: [Function],
     mockReturnThis: [Function],
     mockRestore: [Function] },
}
```

But if I do the same in the other file I get this:

```
function () {
  return fn.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

My suspicion is that `jest.mock` is wrapping the `jest.fn` mock in another function.. any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you mock it like this : `getElementsByTagName: () => 'foo'`?

Comment: 'Calling jest.mock('') returns a useful "automatic mock" you can use to spy on calls to the class constructor and all of its methods. It replaces the ES6 class with a mock constructor, and replaces all of its methods with mock functions that always return undefined.'

Answer (score 13):

## Try using `.mockReturnValue()` after assignment

I encountered the same behavior and found success by calling `mockFn.mockReturnValue(value)` after assignment.

For example:

```js
import { document } from '../../globals.js'

jest.mock('../../globals.js', () => ({
  document: {
    getElementsByTagName: jest.fn()
  }
}))

document.getElementsByTagName.mockReturnValue('foo')

console.log(document.getElementsByTagName()); // this outputs 'foo'
```

I have seen both patterns within the jest documentation.

- See: [`mockFn.mockReturnValue(value)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnvaluevalue) where post-assignment calling is shown.
- See: [`jest.requireActual(moduleName)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename) where calling during assignment is shown.

I wonder if the latter case requires some other pattern of interaction to assert on the mocked return value, but I haven't figured it out. I can't seem to replicate success using the `spyOn` pattern [suggested in another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59891519/2502532).

Comment: So weird... In my case calling `mockImplementation` inside test case worked like a charm, but if I define it inside `jest.mock` it returns `undefined`. Even though mock function is picked up by component

Comment: @Lukenzo You should put this as an answer, the above answer's solution doesn't work, but yours do.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using `react-scripts` to run tests. (Within my `package.json` the `test` attribute was set to `react-scripts test`).

Thankfully, I stumbled on this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73838422/jest-fn-mockreturnvaluehello-returns-undefined-when-called-in-a-beforeall), where I found that by default react-scripts will set [jest.resetMocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#resetmocks-boolean) to `true`. In a standard jest configuration, this is `false`.

This means when running with `react-scripts test`, before every test run, your mock implementation will be completely reset and your mock function will return `undefined`.

A couple ways to fix this:

1. Within your `package.json`, add a `resetMocks: false` to your `jest` configuration:

```json
"jest": {
  ...,
  "resetMocks": false
}
```

2. Define your mock in a `beforeEach` [function](https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown#repeating-setup)