# jest.fn().mockReturnValue("hello") returns undefined when called in a beforeAll() but not in a beforeEach()

Tags: javascript, jestjs

How come when I create a `jest.fn()` function and then call `mockReturnValue("hello")` on it inside of a `beforeAll()` I get `undefined` when I try to console.log the value of it in a test but not when I call the `mockReturnValue("hello")` inside of a `beforeEach()`?

```
import App from "./App"

describe("App", () => {

  const mock = jest.fn()

  beforeAll(() => {
    mock.mockReturnValue("hello")
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
  })

  afterEach(() => {
  })

  afterAll(() => {
  })

  it("should console.log the value 'hello'", () => {
    console.log(mock()) // undefined
  })
})
```

[image: beforeAll print undefined]

however, when I call the `mockReturnValue("hello")` inside a `beforeEach`, it prints `hello`.

```
import App from "./App"

describe("App", () => {

  const mock = jest.fn()

  beforeAll(() => {
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
   mock.mockReturnValue("hello")
  })

  afterEach(() => {
  })

  afterAll(() => {
  })

  it("should console.log the value 'hello'", () => {
    console.log(mock()) // hello
  })
})
```

[image: beforeAll print hello]

Comment: Is this really what you're running locally?  I ask because either version logs "hello" for me, so I'm wondering if there's some mistake here that isn't reflected in your post.

Comment: Hey @MattMorgan

Yeah, when I run both code snippets  in my code editor I get 'undefined' and 'hello'

Ill edit my post and attach some screenshots if possible.

Comment: @MattMorgan. I attached some screenshots.

Comment: Presumably you've set https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#resetmocks-boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe, I was able to track my issue down.

I am running my test via `node_modules/react-scripts` instead of via `node_modules/jest`

by default, according to this other [StackOverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67252912/jest-testing-mock-functions-return-undefined-create-react-app-project#:%7E:text=1-,Answer,-Sorted%20by%3A)

*by default in react-scripts `node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/utils/createJestConfig.js` the jest configuration is set with `"resetMocks": true`*

So what I did, inside of my `package.json` file was put the jest configuration of

```
  "jest": {
    "resetMocks": false
  }
```

And re-ran my test, and it passed as expected